# Does editing your own answer several times inhibit reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

I have edited my own answer to a question on the Mathematics site seven times. The answer got accepted and upvoted, but there is no increment in my reputation.

Does editing your own answer several times inhibit reputation? Or, are there any other factors that inhibit reputation?

Comment: You may see my updated answer to know how you can get the wiki status removed.

Comment: @GarimanSingh Ok. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Glad to see that the Community Wiki status has been removed from your answer.

Comment: @GarimanSingh your answer was really helpful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Editing an answer several times doesn't inhibit reputation from that answer. The problem is that the [answer you posted on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748882) was made a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/771581) by you when you posted it for the first time. It may have been a mistake from your side as you do not seem to be aware of this feature. However, an essential characteristic of Community Wiki posts is that they **belong to the community as a whole**, that is, they can be edited freely by most people to improve them. Thus, the reputation earned from Community Wiki posts goes to no one (except in the case of bounties, in which case, a bounty is awarded to the original poster).

**Note**: Only a moderator can remove Community Wiki status from a post. Since you had mistakenly made your answer a Community Wiki, you may flag it as "in need of moderator intervention" explaining your case. A moderator may revoke the Community Wiki status causing an automatic recalculation of your reputation as if the post was never a wiki. However, it is entirely a decision of the moderators.